# Get all calendars from Outlook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I want to read all available non shared calendars from the current Outlook session with an Excel file through VBA.

I loaded the default calendar with:

```
Set Calendar = outApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(9)
```

I seem to find the available calendars by browsing the Outlook session object manually in the local variable view in the VBA editor. The path to get there (through all session, folder and item hierarchies) is obviously different for every user. So my best solution at the moment is to crawl the whole object till I find a valid calendar. Is there a better solution?

My goal is to identify all available calendars in the current Outlook session and give the user a choice in which calendar he adds a new appointment.

I add the appointment with the following code:

```
Public Sub AddOutlooktermin(subject As String, _
                        startDateTime As Date, _
                        endDateTime As Date, _
                        body As String, _
                        location As String, _
                        allDayEvent As Boolean, _
                        reminderMinutes As Integer, _
                        setReminder As Boolean, _
                        busyStatus As Integer _
                        )
Dim outApp As Object, apptoutapp As Object

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set apptoutapp = outApp.CreateItem(1) 'olAppointmentItem)
With apptoutapp
    .Start = startDateTime
    .End = endDateTime
    .subject = subject
    .body = body
    .location = location
    .allDayEvent = allDayEvent
    .reminderMinutesBeforeStart = reminderMinutes
    .ReminderSet = setReminder
    .busyStatus = busyStatus
    .Categories = "#Urlaub"
    .importance = 2
    .Save
End With
Set apptoutapp = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a calendar folder in Outlook anywhere in the folder tree. Use the [DefaultItemType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865360(v=office.15).aspx) property to find calendar folders in Outlook, it returns a constant from the [OlItemType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869291.aspx) enumeration indicating the default Outlook item type contained in the folder. In case of calendars you should get the olAppointmentItem value.

Also you may use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class to get a Folder object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Calendar folder for the user who is currently logged on.

```
Sub ChangeCurrentFolder()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = _  
 myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)  
End Sub
```

And then iterate through all subfolders.

The Store class provides the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924(v=office.15).aspx) method as well, it returns a Folder object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the FolderType argument. This method is similar to the **GetDefaultFolder** method of the NameSpace object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.